# Is it possible to use Custom TextField for search in appbar (using delegates)?

Tags: flutter

I want to build a search function in my app, many tutorials that I saw were using Search Delegates and showSearch. The search is great and perfectly fine, but the search bar is not suitable for the app style. Is it possible to use a custom text field?
The first picture is the default search bar, and the second one is the goal

[image: Default Search bar]

[image: Before Search button Press][image: The goal]

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom Appbar

```
AppBar(
          backgroundColor: theme.primaryColor,
          iconTheme: theme.primaryIconTheme,
          textTheme: theme.primaryTextTheme,
          elevation: 3,
          brightness: theme.primaryColorBrightness,
          leading: widget.delegate.buildLeading(context),
          title: SizedBox(
            height: ratioScreen * 40,
            child: TextField(
              controller: widget.delegate._queryTextController,
              focusNode: focusNode,
              style: theme.textTheme.headline6,
              textInputAction: widget.delegate.textInputAction,
              keyboardType: widget.delegate.keyboardType,
              onChanged: widget.delegate.onChange,
              onSubmitted: widget.delegate.onSubmit,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: AppColors.mainColor, width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                  hintText: searchFieldLabel,
                  hintStyle: searchFieldStyle,
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10)),
            ),
          ),
          actions: widget.delegate.buildActions(context),
        )
```

Comment: can you also include how to change the appbar from the normal appbar into the search bar?